# Parse error in pattern n

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell.
Got a parse error and dont know what is wrong.

```
fromDecTo :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int]
fromDecTo (n x) | (n < x)   = [n]
                | otherwise = fromDecTo (n `div` x) ++ [n `mod` x]
```

This should convert a decimal number into a number with base x (a.e. hexadecimal).

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fromDecTo :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int]
```

This is a function having *one* argument, a function from integers to integers. This is not what you want: you want a function having two arguments, i.e.

```
fromDecTo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

Similarly, the pattern

```
fromDecTo (n x)
```

expresses the result of applying a function `n` to `x` and then applying `fromDecTo`to the result. This is not what you want, taking two arguments is done with

```
fromDecTo n x
```

As a final note, even if it not customary to do so, it is possible to add parentheses, but with the opposite association. The same type shown above could be written

```
fromDecTo :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

which stresses the fact that functions are curried in Haskell: a binary function is actually a function taking only *one* argument, the first, and returning a function taking *one* other argument, the second, and finally returning the result.

Similarly, instead of

```
fromDecTo n x
```

we could write

```
(fromDecTo n) x
```

since `n` is applied to `fromDecTo` first, and then `x` after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. Here is what you want to achieve:

```
fromDecTo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
fromDecTo n x | (n < x)   = [n]
              | otherwise = fromDecTo (n `div` x) x ++ [n `mod` x]
```